# What is the name of the soldier's mom(and her son the dead soldier) that Tony Stark meets in a bar in Iron Man?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, iron-man-3

In *Iron Man 3*, Does anyone remember the name of the soldier's mom that Tony goes to meet in the bar and preferably also the name of the soldier himself in the file that the mom has with her? I forgot and can't seem to find mention of the name in any of the information I can find.

Answer (score 9):

[IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1300854/fullcredits) lists [Dale Dickey](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0225460/) as playing "**Mrs Davis**" - and she was definitely the mother in the bar. It also lists [James Rackley](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm4540181/) as playing "**Chad Davis**".

[Marvel Cinematic Wiki](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Chad_Davis) confirms that Chad Davis was the soldier in question.

> Although he was pleased with the new life the Extremis virus had given him, Chad grew increasingly concerned about its side effects and procured a file containing information on himself and other Extremis test subjects, which he took with him to his parents' home town of Rose Hill. Before he could do anything with the file however, the Extremis within him went critical and killed him, incinerating another five innocent bystanders in his vicinity.